# how to order the array list in android depending upon keys?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am facing issue for order the array list. Let me share you json data first :-

```
[{
"atbez": "PACKING",
"atwtb": "CKD 2X1",

}, {
"atstd": "X",
"atbez": "PACKING",
"atwtb": "LOOSE*"
}, {
"atbez": "PACKING",
"atwtb": "FULL FITTING"
}]
```

Here is my above json data i want to check if **"atstd": "X"** exists then atwtb value Loose will come at top at rest will come after this. My expected output like below:-

```
LOOSE*
CKD 2X1
FULL FITTING
```

I have tried this below code:-

```
if (atbez.contains("PACKING")) {

    linearPacking.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    String atwtb = jsonObject.getString("atwtb");

   packing.add(atwtb);

   if (jsonObject.has("atstd")) {

       String packString = jsonObject.getString("atstd");

       if(packString.equalsIgnoreCase("x")){

         packing.add(0, atwtb);

     }
    }else {
 }
}
```

Please help me how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you are probably looking for `Collections.sort()` method

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko can you update our code.. that will be helpful for us

Comment: What is the problem for you to do that yourself? Have you checked the documentation? https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
List<String> ordered = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i< arr.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
      String atbez = obj.getString("atbez");
      if (atbez.contains("PACKING")) {
        if(obj.has("atstd") && obj.getString("atstd").equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
          ordered.add(j, obj.getString("atwtb"));
          j ++;
        }
        else {
          ordered.add(obj.getString("atwtb"));
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hello @aditya, i did by my self that time, but this answer will work like charm.

Answer (score 0):

loop through the json-array until you find "atstd": "X", now take the value of "atwtb" and add it to an empty array list, then remove the key "atwtb" from the same json object.

Now loop through the json array again and add all the values from  "atwtb" key to the arraylist.